# How to change column name of time array in julia with new method?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use this old method to assign colnames(I'm not sure is it the better way) on Julia 1.3.1

```
using TimeSeries
ta=readtimearray(IOBuffer("2020/01/05 16:14:01,20"),format="yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS", header=false)
tb=TimeArray(ta, colnames=["cost"])
```

It shows a warning, but I don't understand the message, can anyone explain it?

```
┌ Warning: `TimeArray(d::AbstractVector{D}, v::AbstractArray{T, N}, c::Vector{S}, m::Any=nothing; args...) where {T, N, D <: TimeType, S <: AbstractString}` is deprecated, use `TimeArray(d, v, Symbol.(c), m; args...)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at REPL[23]:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of `TimeSeries` very well, but apparently column names should be symbols now, when they were strings in previous versions.

Something like this should work:

```
using TimeSeries
ta=readtimearray(IOBuffer("2020/01/05 16:14:01,20"),format="yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS", header=false)
tb=TimeArray(ta, colnames=[:cost])
```

Alternatively, if you have your column names as a vector of strings, you can do like the deprecation message suggests and convert this to a vector of symbols:

```
tb=TimeArray(ta, colnames=Symbol.(["cost"]))
```

---

Here is a brief explanation of the warning, as I understand it. The old, deprecated version and the proposed solution respectively look like this:

```
old: TimeArray(d::AbstractVector{D}, v::AbstractArray{T, N}, c::Vector{S}, m::Any=nothing; args...) where {T, N, D <: TimeType, S <: AbstractString}
new: TimeArray(d,                    v,                      Symbol.(c),   m;              args...)
```

We see that changes are related to the `c` argument, which originally was of type `Vector{S} where S<:AbstractString` (i.e. a vector of String-like objects), and should be replaced by `Symbol.(c)`, i.e. the `Symbol` constructor broadcasted (applied elementwise) to such a vector of strings (therefore producing a vector of symbols).

And indeed, looking at the docstring for `TimeArray` makes it clear that the column names should be a vector of symbols:

```
help?> TimeArray
search: TimeArray readtimearray writetimearray

  TimeArray{T,N,D<:TimeType,A<:AbstractArray{T,N}} <: AbstractTimeSeries{T,N,D}


  Constructors
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  TimeArray(timestamp, values[, colnames, meta = nothing])
  TimeArray(ta::TimeArray; timestamp, values, colnames, meta) # <- this is the CTor you're using


[...]


  Arguments
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

    •    timestamp::AbstractVector{<:TimeType}: a vector of sorted timestamps, Each element in this vector should be unique.

    •    timestamp::Symbol: the column name of the time index from the source table. The constructor is used for the Tables.jl package integration.

    •    values::AbstractArray: a data vector or matrix. Its number of rows should match the length of timestamp.

    •    colnames::Vector{Symbol}: the column names. Its length should match the column of values.

    •    meta::Any: a user-defined metadata.
```